# How to transform pandas df containing boolean columns into a heatmap compatible table?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, heatmap, pandas-melt

I have a table something like this:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Where each cell is containing whether the row is connected to the specified column.

I want to transform this into a table like this:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| C | 1 | 2 | 3 |

Where each cell contains the number of rows (from the original table) that has both connected to the specific column and row name in the second table.

For example, the 3 in the second table means that there are 3 rows in the original table that is connected to the B and C columns.

The goal is to plot a heatmap from the second table using plotly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import plotly.express as px



# data for data frame
data = {'A': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 0}, 
        'B': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 0}, 
        'C': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1}}

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# list for our combination values
values = []

# loop over each column combination - 
# AA, AB, AC, BA, BB, BC, CA, CB, CC
for row in df.columns:
    # create a list for each row value
    # first iteration [AA, AB, AC]
    # Second iteration [BA, BB, BC]
    # third iteration [CA, CB, CC]
    temp_val = []
    for col in df.columns:
        # get number of rows that are connected 
        val = sum(df[row] & df[col])
        # add to temp list
        temp_val.append(val)
    # add the row to all rows list
    values.append(temp_val)

# create data frame
heat_df = pd.DataFrame(values, index=df.columns, columns=df.columns)

# plot heatmap
fig = px.imshow(heat_df)
fig.show()
```

Dataframe output:

```
    A   B   C
A   1   1   1
B   1   2   2
C   1   2   3
```

Heatmap:

[image: Output]